# How do you translate "hover over"?

Tags: word-choice, usage, technology

I would like to say something like:

> Please use your mouse to hover over the attribute icon

but I do not know the Chinese equivalent for "hover over", as used in technology / software.

Would 停留 be understood, or is there a better way to say it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called (鼠标)悬停 in mainland China.

> Please use your mouse to hover over the attribute icon
>
> 请将鼠标悬停在属性图标上。

If you search this phrase on the internet you'll see more examples how it's used, e.g.

> 鼠标悬停效果是网页制作的常用特效之一。
>
> 'Mouse over' is one of the most used special effect in web design.

You should note that many Computer related words are translated very differently in mainland China ('zh-cn' in locale terms) and other Chinese speaking regions, especially in Taiwan where there is a complete different set of words. You may want to update your question to clarify your user locale. If it's different from 'zh-cn' you may want to wait for another answer.

Comment: I am aware of the differences in locale. I should have clarified that I did indeed intend to use mainland Chinese for this. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

so what you mean can be you just wanna "say" it in spoken language, or what you really want is put it into something technical like a user's manual where you're pretty sure that it'd better be formal language construct.

---

### Casual

When you wanna just "say" it casually, in spoken language, em, take me as an example, I just say:

> 把鼠標晃到那屬性圖標上頭
>   ba3 shu3 biao1 huang4 dao0 na4 shang4 shu3 xing4 tu2 biao1 shang4 tou2
>   Hover the mouse over that attribute icon, please.

---

### Formal

> 請把滑鼠移動到屬性圖標上方。
>   Pinyin : qing3 ba3 hua2 shu3 yi2 dong4 dao4 shu3 xing4 tu2 biao1 shang4 fang1
>   Please hover the mouse over that attribute icon.

---

### Discussion

Of course, this doesn't necessarily mean a better one. But in the terms of natural feeling, my example shows a commonly used one in my area. You don't wanna presume that all people say it in the same way in such a vast piece of land. Mandarin is one way to make people from different area understand each other, but yet this way has not yet achieved one hundred percent victory.

停留 is a good one too, I use that sometimes and heard about people use that too.

If you need any reference to proof what I'm talking about here is not non-sense or want me to make things clearer, please leave comment.

靜候疑者 (Waiting for any enquiry with open arms.)

Welcome to the world of Chinese language :D

Comment: Not exactly. `把它晃到那上面` means "move the mouse over that" but lacks a particular "... and then stop and wait awhile" sense.

Comment: Yes, it's not so exact translation. Just show you that that's the way I say it orally. By the way, I'm Sichuanese.

Comment: @congliu Can you try to revise your answer to include 1) The fact that this may be a Sichuanese translation and 2) more context behind your answer? Otherwise, this could just be a comment

Comment: @Growler, very helpful suggestion, 君一席話勝在下十年書 (note: this is the translation of "very helpful suggestion") (1) "把它晃到那上面" is not Sichuanese translation, but a Mandarin variant, because you couldn't force everyone in China speak in one variant nor could you say they're not talking in Chinese. Just as Manchu variation of Chinese, similar of Mandarin today doesn't mean it represents Chinese as a whole. (2) 背景固有 然鑒於此貼乃應習者@DavidG君而非應汝之作 固在下實不確汝之疑為何物 是為背景也 P.S. This is a comment.

Comment: First, 悬停 (or 停悬 in Taiwan) is a computer jargon for "hover over", I think the casual one would be OK to explain to newbies but it should not be a formal translation; Second, 鼠标 is used in Mainland as a formal jargon and 滑鼠 is in Taiwan. Why did you particularly distinguish them in the casual case and the formal case?

Comment: 知我者@Stan君也 You got it! Because Taiwanese variant is regarded as orthodox decent from Chinese ancestors. But we Chinese people in mainland "reverse engineering" so that we absorb what is going on in Taiwan, Hong Kong and overseas Chinese communities; we say it both ways.

Comment: For a list of subtle discrepancies between Chinese mainland variant and Taiwan variant, you definitely wanna check out 侯捷's summary: http://jjhou.boolan.com/ and hover your mouse over 英中繁簡編程術語對照 (Terms) please.